# Working with generic constraints

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I know this question has been asked before but I have no idea how to solve this current problem. I have defined a protocol `MultipleChoiceQuestionable` with an `associatedtype` property:

```
protocol Questionable {
    var text: String {get set}
    var givenAnswer: String? {get set}
}

protocol MultipleChoiceQuestionable: Questionable {
    associatedtype Value
    var answers: Value { get }
}

struct OpenQuestion: Questionable {
    var text: String
    var givenAnswer: String?
}

struct MultipleChoiceQuestion: MultipleChoiceQuestionable {
    typealias Value = [String]
    var text: String
    var givenAnswer: String?
    var answers: Value
}

struct NestedMultipleChoiceQuestion: MultipleChoiceQuestionable {
    typealias Value = [MultipleChoiceQuestion]
    var text: String
    var answers: Value
    var givenAnswer: String?
}
```

Types which conform to this protocol are saved in an array as `Questionable` like so:

```
// This array contains OpenQuestion, MultipleChoiceQuestion and NestedMultipleChoiceQuestion
private var questions: [Questionable] = QuestionBuilder.createQuestions()
```

**Somewhere in my code I want to do something like:**

```
let question = questions[index]
if let question = question as? MultipleChoiceQuestionable { 
   // Do something with the answers
      question.answers = .....
}
```

This is not possible because Xcode warns me: *Protocol MultipleChoiceQuestionable can only be used as a generic constraint.* I've been searching around on how to solve this issue since generics are quite new for me. Apparently Swift doesn't know the type of the `associatedtype` during compile time which is the reason this error is thrown. I've read about using type erasure but I don't know if that solves my problem. Maybe I should use generic properties instead or perhaps my protocols are defined wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the action you want to apply to your sub-protocol objects does not rely on the associated type (i.e. neither has the a generic parameter nor returns the generic type) you can introduce an auxiliary protocol which just exposes the properties/methods you need, let your type conform to that protocol, and declare the `question` in terms of that protocol.

For example, if you just want to know some info about the question:

```
protocol MultipleChoiceInfo {
  var numberOfAnswers: Int { get }
}

extension MultipleChoiceQuestion: MultipleChoiceInfo {
  var numberOfAnswers: Int { return answers.count }
}
// do the same for the other multiple-choice types
```

Then you can access the questions through the new protocol like this:

```
let question = questions[index]
if let info = question as? MultipleChoiceInfo {
  print(info.numberOfAnswers)
}
```

As I said, if you cannot provide an abstract (non-generic) interface then this won't work.

**EDIT**

If you need to process the generic data inside your questions you can extract the logic depending on the concrete generic type into another "processing" type which provides an interface to your questions. Each question type then dispatches its data to the processor interface:

```
protocol MultipleChoiceProcessor {
  func process(stringAnswers: [String])
  func process(nestedAnswers: [MultipleChoiceQuestion])
}

protocol MultipleChoiceProxy {
  func apply(processor: MultipleChoiceProcessor)
}

extension MultipleChoiceQuestion: MultipleChoiceProxy {
  func apply(processor: MultipleChoiceProcessor) {
    processor.process(stringAnswers: answers)
  }
}
```

Just create a type conforming to `MultipleChoiceProcessor` and do the type-check dance again:

```
if let proxy = question as? MultipleChoiceProxy {
  proxy.apply(processor:myProcessor)
}
```

---

As an aside, if you don't have more protocols and structs in your real application, you might also just ditch the protocol stuff altogether... for this kind of problem it seems a bit over-engineered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This auxiliary protocol is really awesome and I haven't seen such a design pattern before. The problem is that I really need that answers property which can't be defined in this auxiliary protocol ..  but maybe I should've mentioned that better in my question I'm sorry for that. Am I correct to say there's no other solution for this problem? If so I'll have to rethink the architecture. Thanks again!

Comment: Even though your use case can probably be solved in an easier way without protocols, it's a good example to learn about protocols nontheless :)
For sure there are another solution... I edited my answer.